# How expand UIView or display UIView above the keyboard

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, uiscrollview, keyboard

I have a UIView, where I have a UIScrollView and 6 UITextField had 2 UILabel. When I want to write something to UITextfield, which is low I have this problem:

[image]

The keyboard hidden UITextfields. When I set larger size of UIScrollView, nothing happens. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: You need to add all the controller on UIScrollView and then manage it with contentSize..

Comment: you can't! UIKeyboard display on the top of UIWindow. You should hide the keyboard first

Comment: you can't! UIKeyboard display on the top of UIWindow. you can resolve your problem ,look this https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding

Comment: Duplicate question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1126726/how-to-make-a-uitextfield-move-up-when-keyboard-is-present?rq=1

Comment: Are you using tableView ? if , we can set content offset property to UItableView
or use " TPKeyboardAvoiding " as per the below answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to take Scrollview first. Than add all textfields & labels into it.

Now while clicking on any textfield there is a delegate method calls named textFiledDidBeginEditing. You can set the ScrollView offset in it.

Hope this will help.

Answer (score 4):

TPKeyboardAvoiding lib could be helpful here.

https://github.com/michaeltyson/TPKeyboardAvoiding